# PyGame: How to increase a value after every 10 points?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a relatively simple game made with pygame. The idea is to dodge the blocks (they are called "things" in my code) falling at you. I would like to increase the speed of those blocks after every 10 are dodged. I already have a dodged counter which counts how many are dodged. I know that I can increase the speed with just `thing_speed += 1` after every block is dodged but that makes it essentially impossible after around 30 are dodged. The dodged value is a counter that gets added to after each block goes off the screen.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import base64
import io
import webbrowser

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
grey = (200, 200, 200)

pepe_width = 70
pepe_height = 70

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('The Best Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

photo = 'R0lGODudrGfXe1i..........nzveVVABFSQBYIgIBAA7'
photo2 = 'R0lGADNVMzNVZ............jNVmTOAZmYAAOBAAA7'

output = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(photo))
output2 = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(photo2))

pepeImg = pygame.image.load(output)
bgImg = pygame.image.load(output2)


def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (10, 10))


def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])


def pepe(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(pepeImg, (x, y))


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()


def crash():
    message_display('lel pal u ded')


def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 3.5
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x_change = 0
                    y_change = 0

        x += x_change
        y += y_change
        gameDisplay.blit(bgImg, [0,0])

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        pepe(x, y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - pepe_width or x < 0:
            crash()
        if y > display_height - pepe_width or y < 0:
            crash()

        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            thing_speed += 1

        if (x < thing_startx + thing_width and x + pepe_width > thing_startx and
            y < thing_starty + thing_height and y + pepe_height > thing_starty):
            crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: "impossible" as in too fast? So you want to increase the speed by less than 1? Maybe by 0.1?

Comment: Could you show the version of your code which increases the speed by 1 after every ten dodged blocks? I think the shown code is not doing that. "thing_speed" occurs only in definition and in being used, but not for being increased.

Comment: I added how I increase the speed to the code. It is inside the main_loop function. you can find it under dodged += 1

Comment: Keep in mind that if your player is, say, 70 pixels tall and your speed goes over 70 pixels per second, there's a good chance that the "things" will bypass the player and you will not detect the collision.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for but, you could do a max or a curve to the speed. Say you made it so the block speed only reaches a certain amount.

```
     if thing_speed < max_speed: # you would set this somewhere else
         thing_speed += 1
```

or you could use a curve to make it so they blocks get marginally faster as you dodge more and more of them.

```
curve_amount = 0.2 # I just made this number up, you would have to tweek it.
if dodged: # Im assuming you dodge detection code looks like this.
    thing_speed *= 1+curve_amount
```

or you could use both!

or if you wanted to do it based on number, you could just do a simple counter

```
# counter declared someplace else
if counter == 10:
    thing_speed += 1
    counter = 0
```